# Find duplicate files via SQL table

Tags: python, sql, file, sqlite, duplicates

I have a lot of files (millions), and a lot of them are duplicate files (they are basically repeated backups) and I would like to remove some duplicates semi-automatically creating some queries that identify what to remove.

Let's say that verifying correspondence of name, size and mtime (last time file was changed) would be sufficient to identify a duplicate.

I created a "sqlite" table "files" containing all my files (one record per file) with a python script. Columns are:
1. "path" TEXT
2. "idpath" INT (each different directory have a different idpath)
3. "name" TEXT
4. "size" INT
5. "mtime" INT

**The (not simple) question is: is possible to write a SQL statement that identify which files from a set of files present in a specified directory and all subdirectories (that shares the same initial string characters of the directory searched for duplicates) are present also elsewhere?**

---

Let me make an example with a table filled with following records (fields comma separated):

```
    path           id  name size  mtime
    ------------   --  ---- ----  -----

    /1/1.1       , 1 , a  , 111 , 222
    /1/1.1       , 1 , b  , 111 , 222
    /1/1.1       , 1 , c  , 111 , 222
    /1/1.1       , 1 , e  , 111 , 222

    /1/1.2       , 2 , a  , 111 , 222
    /1/1.2       , 2 , b  , 111 , 8888
    /1/1.2       , 2 , c  , 111 , 222
    /1/1.2       , 2 , f  , 111 , 222
    /1/1.2/1.2.1 , 3 , b  , 111 , 8888
    /1/1.2/1.2.1 , 3 , d  , 111 , 222

    /2/1.1       , 4 , b  , 111 , 222
    /2/1.1       , 4 , c  , 111 , 222
    /2/1.1       , 4 , d  , 111 , 222
```

In this example if the base directory for duplicate removal is set to be **"/1/1.2"** then the query should result in:

```
    /1/1.2       , 2 , a , 111 , 222
    /1/1.2       , 2 , c , 111 , 222
    /1/1.2/1.2.1 , 3 , d , 111 , 222
```

(the first record "a" was find in "/1/1.1", the second "c" in "/1/1.1" and "/2/1.1", and the third "d" in "/2/1.1", and note that "d" was in a subdirectory of the base path)

Note that logically b should not be in result set since is present just in the subdirectory in which files should be deleted and not in the other directories (it has different mtime). Anyway if it would be returned once (but not twice) maybe an alternative solution. f should instead not be in the results because is unique.

---

Let's say that if it helps I can recreate the table or even more tables with python scripts to perform the task (and all required indexes to make it usable! :)).

A more complete solution would identify also entire directories to be removed if all files inside matches as duplicate (in this case it can be considered that all subdirectories structure match perfectly)

Comment: Why won't "SELECT name, size, mtime, COUNT(name) FROM [files] WHERE path like '/1/1.01%'  GROUP BY name, size, mtime HAVING COUNT(name) > 1" work?

Comment: The example output actually has different names; and it would be a good idea to output all the paths (with group_concat).

Comment: Tried the query "SELECT name, size, mtime, COUNT(name) FROM [files] WHERE path like '/1/1.01%' GROUP BY name, size, mtime HAVING COUNT(name) > 1" on the sample data:

Query OK
Row(s) returned: 0

Comment: This is the comma separated example data:
/1/1.1,1,a,111,222;
/1/1.1,1,b,111,222;
/1/1.1,1,c,111,222;
/1/1.2,2,a,111,222;
/1/1.2,2,b,111,8888;
/1/1.2,2,c,111,222;
/1/1.2/1.2.1,3,d,111,222;
/2/1.1,4,b,111,222;
/2/1.1,4,c,111,222;
/2/1.1,4,d,111,222;

Comment: And table structure for import: CREATE TABLE "files" (
    "path" TEXT,
    "idpath" INTEGER,
    "name" TEXT,
    "size" INTEGER,
    "mtime" INTEGER
)

Comment: @DylanB: modified a bit the query '/1/1.1%' instead of '/1/1.01%' but result is the same: 0 records

Comment: PS: even if there would be another record as "/1/1.2/1.2.1,3,b,111,8888" the results should be anyway contain just a,c,d and not b since b is present (twice) just in the subdirectories in which files will be removed!

Comment: Huh.  Try removing the 'having' clause and ordering by the count.

Comment: @DylanB: the result is a,b,c,d all with count 1 (b will have count 2 if query run with the new record added  "/1/1.2/1.2.1,3,b,111,8888")

--SELECT name, size, mtime, COUNT(name) FROM files WHERE path LIKE '/1/1.2%' GROUP BY name, size, mtime ORDER BY COUNT(name)

Comment: Err....  The problem is half-solved once you can pick out those rows with count(2)....  Once you pick those out you need to find the earliest of those rows and NOT delete it.  To accomplish this you will probably want to add a globally unique ID to the table to go along with the other ID's.

Comment: Note that your original question as stated contradicts itself.  One of the requirements in the question is that the files have different names, but in the example expected answer the names are different but you expect them to be results...  This may be part of your problem.

Comment: @DylanB: with your suggestion about half-solved I created a query that would work if just name would be enough to match a duplicate (without considering size and mtime): " SELECT path, name FROM files WHERE path LIKE '/1/1.2%' AND name IN (SELECT name FROM files  WHERE path NOT LIKE '/1/1.2%') "

Comment: Ah.  I had a different approach to de-duplication in mind.  My apologies.  My idea of an approach was to 1) find all the files that had duplicates (original count query), 2) mark all the first files in each result set found as 'safe', then 3) delete the duplicates represented by rows.  I'll have to reconsider your approach, I'm sure it can be done but wasn't my original thought process.  Sorry; I'll come back to this in a few hours.

Comment: Have you looked into fsLint?

Comment: I didn't know fsLint... VERY interesting. Already installed and surely I will use!! (does a lot of other interesting things a part duplicate finding) However it does not use the concepts of the 2 sets when looking for duplicates. I need this concept because I want to delete from old copies what is now present also in other places (e.g. on the freshest backup), maintaining in the old backups just what is not present!